# What is the best way to display a single-paged pdf as an image?

Tags: cocoa, pdf, nsview, nsimage, pdfview

I would like to display in an `NSView` a single-paged PDF.

So far, I have two solutions but they both have downsides. Can anyone help me with any of these downsides?

### First solution: with NSImage and NSImageView

```
   NSString *path= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"pdf"];
   NSImage * image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] ;

   NSImageView * imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] init] ;
   imageView.frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 2*image.size.width, 2*image.size.height) ;
   imageView.image = image ;
   imageView.imageScaling = NSImageScaleAxesIndependently ;

   return imageView
```

*Downsides*:

- the image is not anti-aliased
- I don't understand why the factor `2` is needed. Why does my PDF is displayed smaller in an NSView than it is with the Finder?

### Second solution: with PDFDocument and PDFView

```
    NSString *path= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *urlPDF = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] ;

    PDFDocument * myPDFDocument = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:urlPDF] ;

    PDFView *myPDFView = [[PDFView alloc] init] ;
    myPDFView.document = myPDFDocument ;

    PDFPage * firstPage = [myPDFDocument pageAtIndex:0] ;
    NSRect myBounds = [firstPage boundsForBox:kPDFDisplayBoxMediaBox] ;
    NSRect myNewBounds = NSMakeRect(0, 0, myBounds.size.width*2, myBounds.size.height*2+5) ;

    myPDFView.frame = myNewBounds ;
    myPDFView.autoScales = YES ;

    return myPDFView ;
```

*Downsides*:

- I am able to select the text of my pdf, I can zoom in or zoom out. But I would like my PDF document to be displayed as an image, without these possibilities
- I don't understand why the factor `2` is needed. Why is my PDF displayed smaller in an NSView than it is with the Finder?
- There are some margins around my image

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing the problems you describe with NSImageView. I implemented a nib-based window and NSImageView. In my case I have an overlapping sibling view, so I turned CALayers turned on in the nib. I'm on 10.9.2. Sizing is normal (1x) and the text in my PDF is anti-aliased (sub-pixel I think, since I see colors when I blow it up). I do have scaling NONE - maybe scaling is preventing anti-aliased text?

Otherwise my guess is there's something different about your views or or PDF content. Try a simpler PDF and/or a nib-based view and if it works, you can look for differences.